# How do I "clean" a String in PHP using regex?

Tags: php, regex

For example suppose I have

```
$blah = "C$#@#.a534&";
```

I wish to filter the string so that only letters, numbers and "." remain yielding "C.a534"

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know what characters should be allowed, you can use a negated character group (in a regular expression) to remove everything else:

```
$blah = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\.]/i', '', $blah);
```

Note that i am using the `i` modifier for the regular expression. It matches case-insensitive, so that we do not need to specify `a-z` *and* `A-Z`.

Answer (score 4):

been answered lots of times but:

```
function cleanit($input){
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/s', '', $input);
}


$blah = cleanit("C$#@#.a534&");
```

Comment: You'll need to escape the `.`.

Comment: @Nick, dots inside character classes do need escaping.

Comment: I think the `.` doesn't need to be escaped inside a class. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: yeppers. chars like ( ) \ [ ] ? do tho

Answer (score 2):

you can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)

```
$text = preg_replace('/[' . preg_quote('CHARSYOUDONTWANT','/') .  ']/','',$text);
```

on other case for only chars you want try this,

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^' . preg_quote('CHARSONLYYOUWANT','/') .  ']/','',$text);
```

for example

```
$blah = "C$#@#.a534&";
$blah = preg_replace('/[' . preg_quote('$#@&','/') . ']/','',$blah);
echo $blah;
```

Comment: You should specify the delimiter when using `preg_quote()` so that it can be escaped, too.

Comment: Thanks for notice, delimiter is optional so i did not write its working.

Comment: It is optional, but if i'd try to use `/` in the first parameter, it would not get esacped, since it has no special meaning in regular expressions. This can be prevented by explicitly specifying the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Or do it the other way round:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/','',$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

replace all non-valid characters with the empty string.